# How to send notification from one user to another user using same application

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application in which someone can register as user or as company. If someone registers as user, he will get a list of all the registered companies, from dropdown he can select any company and can send some information to it.
I want that whenever a user selects a company and click the button to submit information to the company, the selected company (has also installed my application and is signed into the app) get a notification.
I am using Firebase for storing user and company details and also to register them.
I don't want to use any third party sever.

Any help will be appreciable. Thanks!!

Comment: Sir I have asked just one question "how to send notification from one user to another" so I don't find it a broad or multiple distinct questions. I have only described the situation in which notification is to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)? FCM can send notifications to user/s from [console](https://console.firebase.google.com) and/or [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

Comment: Yes I tried FCM, but according to documentation i found that it needs a third party server for sending push notifications from API.

Comment: *firebaser here* We actually just released [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), which could take the role of the app server. Have a look at this sample of that: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks! but when i add compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.0.1' dependancy, then i am getting error "Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ" while gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should look into push notifications a little more .

As you are using firebase it is advisable to use FCM. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
This has all the information you will require

There are many good alternatives to FCM too.It won't hurt to look into them either

pushy:https://pushy.me

SNS:https://aws.amazon.com/sns

push Whoosh:http://androidbash.com/android-pushwoosh-integration/

Comment: Thanks for the help but I tried FCM, according to documentation i found that it needs a third party server for sending push notifications from API. Am i wrong? Is there any way to send push notification from API from FCM without using third party server as pushy,SNS and other services are paid. So i don't want to prefer it. @Allan Banis